# Ray on_train_result callback retrieving episode_id

Tags: python, ray

I am using the APEX-DQN Agent (AsyncReplayOptimizer) from Ray/RLLib.

I want to use some episode data 
`info["episode"].user_data` from the callback `on_episode_end(info)` to alter the `info["result"]` dictionary in `on_train_result(info)`.

Is there anyway to do that? Since the object `info` output from the two callbacks are very different.

`on_episode_end(info)` : gives "env" and "episode"
`on_train_result(info)` : gives "agent" and "result"

And the "result" from `on_train_result(info)` doesn't give much information on the episodes ran.

I find it weird that the "result" only gives information like

```
'result':{
      'episode_reward_max':13010.0,
      'episode_reward_min':12150.0,
      'episode_reward_mean':12580.0,
      'episode_len_mean':50.0,
      'episodes_this_iter':2,
      'episodes_total':2,
      ...
}
```

without any information on the id's of the episodes ran. If there were episode id's maybe I could try linking the two callbacks together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that results are a summary over many different episodes on different machines, so the episode info is not accessible. In the on_episode_end call back you can save metrics to episode.custom_metrics however, and these will show up in the result object.

https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-training.html#callbacks-and-custom-metrics